# How to use a variable in a thmnote

Tags: environments, theorems, amsthm, variable

I'd like to have the "theorem name" of a theorem be populated using a variable.  It isn't working as I had hoped, see below.  I'm especially confused because I can successfully get the "proof name" of a proof environment be populated by a variable, and the two seem analogous.  Can anyone suggest a workaround?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\def\thmname{baz}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}


% Expected behavior.
% Result displays as Theorem (foo). Hello world.
\begin{theorem}[foo]
  Hello world.
\end{theorem}

% Unexpected behavior.
% Result displays as Theorem (). Hello world.
\begin{theorem}[\thmname]
  Hello world.
\end{theorem}

% Expected behavior.
% Result displays as Theorem. baz.
\begin{theorem}
  \thmname.
\end{theorem}

% Expected behavior.
% Result displays as baz. Hello world.
\begin{proof}[\thmname]
  Hello world.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

While you've already figured out the **why**, here's a suggestion on how you can avoid it in the future.

**Don't use `\def`, use `\newcommand`.** (Unless you really, really know what you are doing.)

One of the features of `\newcommand` is that it performs a check so that you don't overwrite macros defined elsewhere already. If you had used `\newcommand\thmname{baz}` instead of `\def...`, LaTeX would've complained:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)

! LaTeX Error: Command \thmname already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the variable name from `thmname` to `bopthmname` fixed this! Presumably, the variable name `thmname` was already taken and my use was conflicting.

It was blind luck that I ever figured this out ... hat tip to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3188476 which had some comments on this kind of pitfall.